# Probability (boxes)

Tags: probability

A contest consists in choosing one of three boxes that are covered, inside of which there are envelopes and only one of these envelopes contains the prize. Box 1 contains 8 envelopes, box 2 contains 5 envelopes, and box 3 contains 4 envelopes. Which of the following statements is (are) true?

I) The probability of winning the prize if box 3 is chosen is 1/12.

II) If the contester won, the probability that the envelope he chose came from box 2 is 8/23.

III) If the contester loses, the probability that the envelope comes from box 1 is 35/97.

Now, I'm confused because, in my opinion, this problem is ambiguous, I don't know if there's only one envelope containing the prize out of all envelopes, or one for every box.
Please help me make sense out of this problem. The answer according to the source is: all of the above.

Comment: One prize in each box or one prize in total?

Comment: I would personally interpret it as there are a total of 17 envelopes.  Exactly one of the 17 envelopes contains the prize (*implied from the phrase: "and only one of these envelopes contains the prize"*).  You can always choose to solve both interpretations of the problem, or if this is a graded assignment, contact the teacher and ask which is the correct interpretation.

Comment: *From the wording alone* I would lean to one envelope with a prize, **but** from the answers I am pretty sure each box has a prize. For one thing, if it is one prize only, all the answers are false.  Poor wording.

Comment: Where did you get the questions from? Are you able to clarify with the person who ask the question? Are you able to solve the questions under these two interpretation?

Comment: The problem is hopelessly misstated. In addition to the problems already noted, in the first sentence and in I) a box is chosen whereas in II) an envelope is chosen.

Comment: I took it from a supplementary study guide.
Unfortunately, I cannot get in touch with the person who put it together.
By the way, I forgot to point out what the answer, according to the guide, is: all of the above.
I absolutely agree with what all of you have said, I also believe that I) is poorly written because if the person already chose box 3 the probability of winning (if there's a winning envelope in every box) is 1/4, not 1/12 which is both the probability of choosing box 3 and then winning given that box 3 was chosen. However, I would still like help in trying to solve this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can "reverse engineer" what this problem most likely meant by noting that

$${8\over23}={{1\over5}\over{1\over8}+{1\over5}+{1\over4}}$$

and

$${35\over97}={{7\over8}\over{7\over8}+{4\over5}+{3\over4}}$$

That is, if the idea is that the contestant first picks a box at random and then, from among the envelopes in that box, picks an envelope at random, then statements II and III are true.  We might then argue that (mis)statement I is a garbled form of "The probability the contestant will pick box 3 and win the the prize is $1/12$."

Comment: Thank you very much! Now, I have a question, why if I calculate the probability that the envelope that the winner chose came from box 1 and substract 1 from that I don't get 35/97 but 18/23? If I substract 1 from any given probability I should get the counterpart of said probability, i.e. the probability that that event doesn't occur.

Comment: @Jose, it's because these two probabilities are not complementary.  Each is a *conditional* probability, and they refer to different conditions.

Comment: I appreciate your help very much, Barry! :)

Comment: @Jose, you are welcome!